# Como adicionar uma rolagem horizontal no CSS?

Tags: html, css

Como, por exemplo, no site do Netflix quando os filmes vão rolando horizontalmente.

Comment: Alguma resolveu?

Answer (score 3):

Depende do que você quer fazer. Essencialmente é isto:

```
body { //aqui pode ser outro elemento específico que quiser
    overflow-x: hidden; //se realmente quer impedir que tenha uma barra horizontal.
    overflow-y: scroll; //pode-se usar auto para deixar o browser decidir quando usar.
    white-space: nowrap; //n]ao deixa quebrar a linha
}
```

O ideal é aplicar técnicas certas em situações específicas. Seria mais fácil fornecer respostas relevantes se você tivesse postado como está usando.

```css
body { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/0/a/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/0/b/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/0/c/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/0/d/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/0/e/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/people/0/f/">
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Scrollbar.js).

Comment: quero por exemplo... Quando passar o mouse por cima da ceta a direita da imagem (estarão disponíveis duas, uma a esquerda e outra a direita), aconteça uma rolagem automática apresentando outras imagens.

Comment: Você tem algum código do que está fazendo? Coloque na pergunta para mostrar onde o CSS precisa ser aplicado.

Comment: não tenho, só tenho as imagens!
não tenho ideia de como vou montar isso, uso iframe ou não, se vou precisar de javascript kk

Comment: quero um esquema igual do netflix só que menor, em 150px por 150px por exemplo!

Comment: Não tenho como ver isto, eu teria que ver o seu código. Até porque o seu pode ser diferente e não dar para aplicar algo igual ao Netflix. Sua pergunta fala em barra de rolagem horizontal. É assim que faz, eu só posso ser mais específico se a pergunta for mais específica.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `display:inline-block` com `white-space:nowrap` e `overflow-x: scroll` e
    `overflow-y: hidden` Mais ou menos assim:

```
.scroll { 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    white-space:nowrap;
} 

img { 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #999; 
    margin: 2px;
    max-height: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**Veja:** http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/844/